# How to write a list container into a file by binary mode in c++

Tags: c++, list, stl, binaryfiles

I have a problem in a module which needs saving a list of user defined class 'Product' into a binary file and vice-versa.
I have the following code:
Product' is the user defined class of which the list is created.

```
    class Product
    {
        private:
             long int Product_no;
             std::string Product_name;
             double Product_price;
             int Product_qty;
             double Product_tax;
             double Product_dis;

        public:

            //Constructor
            Product();
            Product(long int, string, double, int, double, double);
            Product(long int, double, int, double, double);
            //All Getter methods
            //All Setter methods   
    };
```

and have created the the list as:

```
 list<Product> product_list;
```

and the file to write is opened as follows:

```
ofstream out("products.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

I have tried the following thing:
1.using the write function

```
output.write((char*)&product_list.begin(),sizeof(Product));
```

and have read about:

2.First convert to some structure,without doing this i won't be able to fetch data correctly from file to again create a Product list.

Which is the right way to implement the required features of storing and retrieving?
The code i am thinking of to read from binary file is as follows:

```
Product &p;
while(in.read((char*)&p,sizeof(Product)))
    {
        p->Display_Product();
        Productlist.push_back(p);
    }
```

Is that correct way of reading the details?

Comment: Those are completely different approaches, and your question is like - what should I use to make breakfast, toster or blender?

Comment: You should look into a serialization library. That will help you store user defined classes to a binary representation, and retrieve them later. If you try to do it yourself you have to worry about endianness, padding, etc.

Comment: You should prefer a human-readable file format. See [The Art of Unix Programming, Chapter 5](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/textualitychapter.html)

Comment: ^ JSON, XML, CSV comes to mind. Plenty of libraries for that out there already. Otherwise BSON if a binary format is really required?

Answer (score 1):

The most crucial part is figuring out what you need to do to write a `Product` to a file and read one from a file. Once you have figured that out, it is easy to work with a list.

1. Write the number of items in the list.
2. Iterate over the list and write each item from the list.

Reading them back is just as simple.

1. Read the number of items.
2. Read one item at a time and add them to a list.

The other aspect of writing and reading from a binary file is the issue of portability.

Do you need to share the binary file with other users? If so, are they on the same platform?

Do you expect the files to be useful for a short period (like a semester of school) or long period (years in a company)?

The answers to those will determine how you write the binary data and read them back.

The answers to those will determine how to implement writing and reading of not only a `Product` but also the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

There have some errors in your uasage:

```
copy(Product_list.begin(), Product_list.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Product>(output, "  "));
```

in this usage, first you need override `cout operator` for class `Product`, second in this way you only can write the objects to `text` mode, not `binary`.

```
output.write((char*)&product_list.begin(), product_list.size()*sizeof(Product));
```

This way is also not right, please read: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs380/HANDOUTS/cppBinaryFileIO-2.html

**The right way is:**

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("hello.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
for(auto iter = Product_list.begin(); iter!=Product_list.end(); iter++)
{
    Product_list& product = *iter;
    infile.write(static_cast<const char*>(&product), sizeof(product));
}
```

Comment: what exactly the line Product_list& product =* iter does?Because the write function need a character pointer as first argument,please explain how this is actually working. My list(Product_list) is a list of the class Product.

Comment: @Omkar I have updated the answer, you  can covert to `const char*`.

Comment: But still shouldn't it be Product &product=*iter instead?

Comment: @Omkar No, it not need

Comment: @BlackMambaBut it then says product undefined. Also, i have written the following code for reading the wriiten contents now,but getting an exception it it                :               Product product;
  input.read((char*)&product, sizeof(product));
  Productlist.push_back(product);